# Control+Tab does not work anywhere anymore (Control+Shift+Tab still works)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Running Windows 8.1 64bit.

I have noticed since a couple of days ago that my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut does not work anymore. Not on text editors, not on web browsers, not on property pages, nowhere.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (reverse tab navigation) still works.

I have checked the results on an application called "Ethervane ActiveHotkeys". In there, it states that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not an active hotkey but that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> IS. I assume that some application decided to globally pick up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for itself.

I have tried restarting (and testing as quickly as possible before all programs load), I have tried closing down all applications that the task manager will let me and still the shortcut does not work.

I'm stumped as to how to troubleshoot this further and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. What is your operating system and version? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry about that, I've been running Windows 8.1 64bits for a while. I updated the question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem has been solved by NVIDIA.**

> It is NVIDIA's fault.
>
> Workaround: Uncheck **"Allow Desktop Capture"** in
>   Experience/ShadowPlay options and reboot.
>
> Problem is known and hopefully they are working on it.
>
> Thank you very much Armless John for posting your solution over
>   here...
>
> Source:
>   http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/549286/controltab-does-not-work-anywhere-anymore-controlshifttab-still-works/

**Problem has been solved by NVIDIA.**