# Left ctrl+tab does not work but right ctrl+tab works

Tags: laptop, hotkeys

I am aware there are questions with similar names, but I think the problem is different. Such as the following:

[Question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/816661/ctrltab-not-working-in-any-programs/)

[Question 2](https://superuser.com/questions/814764/controltab-does-not-work-anywhere-anymore-controlshifttab-still-works/)

However, what I am experiencing is quite different. Let me first describe it a little in detail. I have a dual-booted HP Pavilion laptop with 64-bit Linux mint and 64-bit Windows 10 Operating systems. The following issue is in both operating systems.

```
left ctrl+tab: does not work
left ctrl+shift+tab: works
left ctrl+t: does not work
left ctrl+Pgup: does not work
left ctrl+PgDn: does work
right ctrl+tab: works
right ctrl+shift+tab: does not work
right ctrl+t: does work
right ctrl+Pgup: does work
right ctrl+PgDn: does not work
```

I thought the behavior is attributed to Nvidia. However, a system restore would not fix the problem. I also tried uninstalling all the Nvidia software off my computer which proved to no avail. I rebooted Windows in Safe Mode and the problem still persisted. The hotkeys do not work anywhere: not the browser, task manager, etc. When I use an external keyboard, all functionality is available Help would be greatly appreciated!

I do not think it is related to my laptop, but here is my laptop model:

HP Pavilion - 15t Laptop;
Product number: M7H64AV

Comment: Does Left-Ctrl function for other key combinations, or does it not function at all? In the later case, verify the physical keyboard and the registry [Keyboard Layout](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: @itzjustricky Can you connect an external keyboard and check whether the key combinations work?

Comment: @RahulBasu the key combinations work with an external keybord

Comment: @harrymc they Left-Ctrl function for some key combinations.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a problem with key rollover, but that would be quite ridiculous to have it happen with two keys. Most keyboards should be a minimum of 3-key rollover Is the laptop new?

Comment: @Bob yeah the laptop is quite new

Comment: @itzjustricky Can you test an in-store model to see if it has this problem? Can you return it under warranty? It really sounds like a hardware issue. Oh, and check the settings in the firmware (BIOS/UEFI) to see if there's anything that might be relevant - I know HP laptops like to have at least a fn-related setting.

Comment: @Bob I will try to see if I can test an in-store model, but the laptop was fine for the first 4 months I had it. I have tried switching the BIOS settings to see if it would have an effect. Switching the fn-related setting on and off did not seem to change anything.

Comment: @itzjustricky Did it start happening after a software installation or update? It's really sounding like a hardware problem to me, and therefore warranty-worthy.

Answer (score 2):

This is an internal issue but is easily fixable with a 3rd party program called Sharpkeys. Sharpkeys requires Microsoft .NET framework 4.0 or more.

Steps:

- Install Sharpkeys from their website [here](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).
- Click "add" and map Left Ctrl(00_1D) to Right Ctrl(E0_1D).

This will map the left ctrl to act like the right ctrl and will fix your problem.

**EDIT :** Can you try [this](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02783186) out? It's not your model but try it out. According to this site, it says that an external keyboard will work.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me :(.  it seems this writes to the Windows registry, but my problem persists in my Ubuntu OS as well so I didn't think it would work for me. I still want to thank you for your effort.

Comment: -edit above
I did not know I could change the BIOS information via the Registry Editor. So maybe the reason your solution is not working is because it is not compatible with Windows 10. I will look more into this.

Comment: Let me check if there is an easier way to fix this issue.